# QjackCtrl audio server starting. Focusrite Saffire PRO40 card start and no sound

Tags: sound, jack

QjackCtrl server is starting. Then the FW Active LED of the soundcard turn on. I try listenning to a Youtube video and I get no output sound. The card connection setup is working on Windows.

Setup:

Ubuntu 11.10 X64/
QjackCtrl/Ubuntu Studio Controls/ 
Focusrite Saffire PRO40

[image: Setup]

[image]

Here the log from QjackCtrl:

```
19:30:14.614 Patchbay deactivated.
19:30:14.698 Statistics reset.
19:30:14.735 ALSA connection change.
19:30:14.977 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
19:30:14.984 ALSA connection graph change.
19:30:46.140 D-BUS: JACK server is starting...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: driver "firewire" selected
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Saving settings to "/home/richard/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: Starting jack server...
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
Sun Mar 18 19:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot lock down memory area (Cannot allocate memory)[0m
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
19:30:46.552 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 1_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: New client 'firewire_pcm' with PID 0
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 2_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 3_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 4_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 5_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 6_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 7_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_IP 8_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_SPDIF L_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_SPDIF R_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_midi 0_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 1_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 2_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 3_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 4_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 5_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 6_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 7_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 8_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Loop 1_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Loop 2_in'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Mon 1_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Mon 2_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 3_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 4_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 5_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 6_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 7_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 8_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 9_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_Line 10_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_SPDIF L_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_SPDIF R_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_midi 0_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 1_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 2_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 3_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 4_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 5_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 6_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 7_out'
Sun Mar 18 19:30:46 2012: graph reorder: new port 'firewire_pcm:00130e0401400d6b_ADAT 8_out'
19:30:48.759 JACK connection change.
19:30:48.761 Server configuration saved to "/home/richard/.jackdrc".
19:30:48.765 Statistics reset.
19:30:48.775 Client activated.
19:30:48.780 JACK connection graph change.
Cannot lock down memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Sun Mar 18 19:30:48 2012: New client 'qjackctl' with PID 2138
19:33:24.467 XRUN callback (1).
19:37:36.111 XRUN callback (2).
19:38:08.115 XRUN callback (3).
19:38:42.392 XRUN callback (4).
19:38:49.831 XRUN callback (5).
19:39:13.111 XRUN callback (6).
19:43:01.703 XRUN callback (7).
```

[image: QjackCtrl]

I tried lots of different memory settings because log say it can't get a lock. Also server wont start with RealTime option ticked. After server start, the system get unstable. If I try to stop the server, FW active LED on the card shutoff as it should then QjackCtrl freeze.

Any input is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your user-account needs to be in the system-group audio. Please check that in the system-tool for groups and users. Some overlays also create a group named jack or jack-users, check those as well and don't worry: being in one of these groups without need to be wont hurt much ;-)

Regarding the sound itself:

Have you checked the mixer-settings? Some devices are supported by `ffadomixer`, the Focusrite-Gear is known to be supported quite well....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a very old topic and I can't verify if your solution is working. I was trying to convert my father to Linux but it's easier for him to simply use Windows.